# eclipse adt how to set build to release mode

Tags: android

I am using eclipse + ADT

I have my phone connected and am able to test the app by deploying from eclipse adt

Now for some inapp billing purposes - I would like to build and deploy the app to the phone and then test

It seems that Android does not like the in app billing testing without a release signed apk on device

so my question is - how do I get a release signed apk on the device without having to go through the painful piece of " File >> Export "

Thanks

shankar

Comment: the painful piece of " File >> Export " >> made my day :)

Comment: You can use Gradle for this :)

Comment: @samsad - thanks - never have  used gradle - guess its time I learn something new ! :)